# Product not definable by addition in Th($\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,0,1,<)$

Tags: logic, model-theory

I want to prove that in the theory $T$ of ordered fields, multiplication is no definible by addition, i.e, there´s no formula $\phi(x,y,z)$ in $\lbrace 0,1,+ \rbrace$ such that $T\vDash\phi(x,y,z)\Leftrightarrow x\cdot y=z.$

I want to use quantifier elimination or model completness but I don´t arrive to anything, if some one can help me I'll apreciate a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Either `\times` or `\cdot` are better than `*`.

Comment: Is $T$ meant to be the theory of ordered fields as indicated in the question body, or the theory of fields as indicated by the title giving signature without a relation $<$ ?  (Certainly, in $\mathbb{R}$, the order relation is first-order definable using only the language of fields; however, in general ordered fields such as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, it isn't.)

Comment: You say you want to use quantifier elimination. Have you proven that the theory of $(\mathbb{R};+,0,1)$ has quantifier elimination?

Comment: Also, the title asks about definability in the structure $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,0,1)$, while the body asks about definability relative to the theory of ordered fields. These are different - which do you mean?

Comment: You are rigth I just forget to put "<" symbol in title

Comment: But still, the theory of the reals as an ordered field is the theory of real closed fields, which is a *completion* of the theory of ordered fields. So again, which do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to do this is to use *automorphisms*: if there's an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R};0,1,+)$ which isn't an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}; 0,1,+,\times)$, then $\times$ isn't definable in $(\mathbb{R}; 0,1,+)$.

Now there's a useful fact here: the structure $(\mathbb{R};0,1,+,\times)$ has *no nontrivial automorphisms at all* (if you haven't seen this before, it's a good exercise). So, you'll be done if you can find a single nontrivial automorphism of $(\mathbb{R};0,1,+)$. Do you see how to do this?

*HINT: Think of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space ...*

Comment: You're heavily relying on choice here. Which raises the obvious question, is it still true without choice? And the obvious answer should be that the answer is at least somewhat yes, since this is sufficiently absolute statement and you can force to well-order the reals (of the universe, even if you ended up adding more in the process). Nice proof. (Yes, I did just pat myself on the back.)

Comment: I'm trying to use the automorphism f(x)=x+1. But I'm having some trouble showing that it's not an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}; 0,1+, x)$. Could you give me some hints on how to proceed? Thanks!