# Product in $\mathbb{R}$ is not defined by addition

Tags: logic, model-theory

This is a follow up question on: [Product not definable by addition in Th($\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,0,1,<)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3020792/product-not-definable-by-addition-in-th-mathbbr-cdot-0-1).

I've shown that the only automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, 0,1, +, - , \cdot)$ is the identity map.

But I'm having trouble to find an example non-trivial automorphism of $(\mathbb{R},0, 1, +)$ that fixes $\mathbb{R}$ pointwise  and show it's it's not definable.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Fixes R pointwise"? If an automorphism of R fixes R pointwise, it's trivial, by definition.

Comment: hmm.. I'm confused because there's this theorem saying if $N \subset M^n$ is $A$-definable, and $f$ is an automorphism of $\mathcal{M}$ point wise, then $F(N)=N$. So I thought that to prove something that's not definable, we needed to find an automorphism that doesn't fix $\mathbb{R}$ point wise in $(\mathbb{R},0 ,1, + - , \cdot)$, but in ${\mathbb{R},0,1+}$

Comment: @cciirrcclllee the condition that you're looking for is that $f$ is an automorphisms of $\mathcal{M}$ that preserves $A$ pointwise

Comment: to "fix $A$ pointwise" means that $f(a)=a$ for any $a\in A$, so if $f$ fixes all of $M$ pointwise then it is the identity map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a bit of confusion about the relationship between definable subsets and automorphisms. The result we want to use here is that, if $A\subseteq M$ is a subset of an $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathfrak{M}$, then every subset of $M^n$ that is definable over $A$ (ie, that is definable by a formula in the expanded language $\mathcal{L}\cup A$) is fixed by any automorphism of $\mathfrak{M}$ that fixes $A$ pointwise. Can you see why this is?

In particular, if we're trying to show that multiplication is not definable in $(\mathbb{R}, 0, 1, +)$, (note that "definable" is just shorthand for "definable over $\emptyset$"), it suffices to find *any* automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, 0, 1, +)$ that does not preserve multiplication. (Because any such map vacuously fixes $\emptyset$ pointwise.) In particular, we're not looking for automorphisms of $\mathbb{R}$ that "fix $\mathbb{R}$ pointwise", for as Alex points out any such map is the identity map by definition.

Now, if you know that $(\mathbb{R}, 0, 1, +, \cdot)$ has no non-trivial automorphisms, then we just need to find any non-trivial automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}, 0, 1, +)$, for any such map will not preserve multiplication. To do this, extend the element $x_0=1$ to a basis $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ considered as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Then any non-trivial permutation of the basis defines a non-trivial linear isomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself; choose any such isomorphism that fixes $x_0=1$. By definition of linear maps, this map will fix $0$ and preserve addition, and since it also preserves $1$ by construction it is a non-trivial $\mathcal{L}$-automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$, as desired.

Comment: When you say extend $x_0=1 $ to a basis $(x_i)$ of $\mathbb{R}$ considered as a $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space, I'm a little confused about the dimension of the vector space. Will it just be 1? Or are we considering the the basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$? Thanks!

Comment: @cciirrcclllee in fact we have that the dimension of $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is infinite. you can prove this by a simple cardinality argument; if a vector space has dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then it is isomorphic to the vector space $\mathbb{Q}^n$, which has countable cardinality. since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, it hence cannot be finite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: (@cciirrcclllee if it's a bit disorienting to think of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, it's worth playing around with some elements. for instance, can you prove that, for any $\alpha$ an irrational number, $\alpha$ and $1$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$?)

Comment: (@cciirrcclllee I guess I should first ask; can you see why $\mathbb{R}$ can be considered as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$?)

Comment: Oh I see! So if we consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, would the basis $(e_i)_i$ be considered as a trivial basis, where $e_i= (0, \cdots, 1, \cdots)$? Thank you so much!

Comment: @cciirrcclllee so, writing elements in coordinates like that actually implicitly assumes that you already *have* chosen a basis; does this make sense? a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ will actually just "look like" (countably) infinitely many elements of $\mathbb{R}$. in fact, you need the axiom of choice to show that such a basis exists, so by its very nature it won't be possible to write down what all the elements of such a basis would look like. however, to give some intuition, try showing for example that the set $\{1,\sqrt 2 ,\sqrt 3\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: (and hence, that those three elements form part of a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$). remember that a basis for a vector space is just a particular kind of subset of the vector space

Comment: Sorry one more question. What is a permutation of a basis? Is it just switching the order of the vectors? Thanks!